# object value changes after declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, variables, declaration

I'm having this weird issue in JavaScript where the first line has some value then after fetching data from another source of information that isn't related (in code) to the first one in any way the first one changes value (even though it is constant and is not updated in the background).

I'm using:

```
Node: v16.6.1
On: Windows
```

I tried instantiating new instances of those when declaring value with `new Array` or `Array.from(<Map>.values())` but the same weird thing seems to be happening and I cannot seem to find a fix for this.

Code:

```js
  const oldCache = this.client.inviteCache.get(member.guild.id);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(oldCache.map(invite => invite.uses)));
  const newCache = await member.guild.invites.fetch().catch(this.client.noop);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(oldCache.map(invite => invite.uses)));
```

Output:

```js
[6,0]
[7,0]
```

Comment: Sounds like both functions are using the same object. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(oldCache.map(invite => (console.log(invite.uses === oldCache.uses), invite.uses)));` see if it shows "false", if it does - I'm wrong than.

Comment: "*and is not updated in the background*" - how do you know that `invites.fetch()` does not update the array that you got from the `inviteCache`? I would in fact very much expect it to be updated.